# How to request Allow management of all files permission in Flutter Android 11 (R)

Tags: flutter, storage, android-permissions, file-permissions

I'm using Permission Handler package i.e. https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

and I requested `Permission.storage` but it's allowing me only `allow access to media only` I want Allow management of all files by default...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   Permission.manageExternalStorage
```

instead of

```
   Permission.storage
```

and also add following permission to menefiest under manifest tag.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

I am using following package for requesting permission.

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: Hi, I need to set this in my app just to be able to list PDF files in the directory. It seems a bit excessive because I only want to allow users to select a PDF file from storage and it will set a link to that file.

Is there a way around this to allow PDFs as well as media files? I think it might be hard to get the app published if it is requesting manage storage.